# How does my windows application which calls an REST API (using Entity Framework) use the models generated by EF

Tags: rest, entity-framework-core

I have a REST API (.NET CORE 3.1) which uses entity Framework. I have the API built and tested and it all works as designed. (yeah!)

Now, I have a windows app which will call this API (located on another server across the internet). I can call the API from the windows app and get a JSON response. (Again, yeah!)

Now, How do I access the models to deserialize into a strongly typed variable? Do I need to constantly copy the models from the API into my calling application so I have a version of the entity in both places?

Sorry. Very new to EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual approach is to have your model classes distinct from the one you transfer via your REST API. For transferring data, the standard is to use DTOs (data transfer objects).

They are usually just an optimized version of your model classes. You can define your DTOs in their own library project and then just reuse the same project server and client side.

See [Create Data Transfer Objects (DTOs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5) (a little dated) or many other examples online.

A typical library that many use is [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) to map the model classes to DTOs.